# All possible combination of binary matrix with constraint

Tags: r, dataframe

I have three stores in my problem, selling 3 products as shown in the attached picture. The stores are denoted by s1 to s3 and products by p1 to p3. A line between store and product denotes that stores sells a product.

[image: map of stores and products]

I am defining my stores by `stores<-c("s1","s2","s3")` and the products by `products <- c("p1","p2","p3")`.

I have to generate all possible combinations of the store - product  mapping. My main constraint is : each store will sell at least one product and each product will be sold by at least one store.

The current matrix will look like the following

```
   p1 p2 p3
s1 1  0  0
s2 0  0  1
s3 0  1  0
```

For this matrix i need to find out all possible binary combinations such that, the colsums and rowsums are minimum 1 (for the constraint).

Any suggestion, how to achieve this. My actual problem has >20 stores and products.

EDIT: apologies for the confusion. Let me try to put what possible solutions I am after. Intuitively, I am looking for addition of the lines between stores and products starting from the current configuration shown in the picture. I will need all possible matrices, which satisfy the constraint on rowSum and colSum.

```
Existing matrix
   p1 p2 p3
s1 1  0  0
s2 0  0  1
s3 0  1  0

Desired example matrices (addition of one link)
   p1 p2 p3
s1 1  0  1
s2 0  0  1
s3 0  1  0

   p1 p2 p3
s1 1  1  0
s2 0  0  1
s3 0  1  0
```

etc.

Undesired matrix : first row has sum of 0 that is s1 does not sell any product.

```
   p1 p2 p3
s1 0  0  0
s2 0  0  1
s3 0  1  0
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you want all possible matrices of a certain dimension with values such that their row and column sum equals to 1? Could you edit your question to include the desired output?

Comment: @vivek, check the answer

Comment: @MauritsEvers, thanks for your inputs, I have updated the desired output. Please let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: @Hardikgupta Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want to describe all possible combinations of mappings (interactions) between stores (rows) and products (columns). In the interaction matrix, an interaction is encoded by `1`, its absence by `0`. The constraint is that the column and row sum are greater equal `1`.

This is an interesting combinatorics question; my approach by enumerating all possible combinations is not very efficient; I'm sure there are much more efficient implementations that take into account possible symmetries of the matrices. It'd be interesting to see other solutions...

In the following, I make use of function `gtools::permutations`.

```
matrixCombn <- function(nrow, ncol) {
    # All possible column combinations for a matrix of dimension dim
    # Here we assume two different values c(1, 0)
    require(gtools);
    columns <- t(permutations(n = 2, r = nrow, v = c(1, 0), repeats.allowed = TRUE));
    columns <- columns[, colSums(columns) > 0];

    # Construct all possible combinations of dim column vectors and
    # impose constraint that row and column sum >= 1
    ret <- lapply(as.data.frame(t(permutations(ncol(columns), ncol, repeats.allowed = TRUE))), function(x) {
        m.cand <- columns[, x];
        if (all(rowSums(m.cand) > 0) & all(colSums(m.cand) > 0)) m.cand else NULL;
    })
    ret <- Filter(Negate(is.null), ret);
    return(ret);
}

# Example for 3x3 interaction matrix design
ret <- matrixCombn(3, 3);
```

This gives us 265 unique combinations

```
length(ret);
# [1] 265
```

For example, here are the first 3

```
ret[1:3];
#$V6
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    0    0    1
#[2,]    0    0    1
#[3,]    1    1    0

#$V7
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    0    0    1
#[2,]    0    0    1
#[3,]    1    1    1

#$V11
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    0    0    1
#[2,]    0    1    0
#[3,]    1    0    0
```

---

For a `3x2` interaction matrix design we get

```
ret <- matrixCombn(3, 2);
length(ret);
# [1] 25
```

with the first 3 combinations

```
ret[1:3];
#$V6
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    0    1
#[2,]    0    1
#[3,]    1    0

#$V7
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    0    1
#[2,]    0    1
#[3,]    1    1

#$V12
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    0    1
#[2,]    1    0
#[3,]    0    1
```

Comment: I modify the program as follows to get row and column dimension separately (just in case I have different stores and products). I used dim1 for columns <-; and dim2 for the calculation of ret. I believe this will make it general. Any caveat in this approach ?

Comment: I tested the solution with dim = 2, and it did not gave me the matrix with all the components are ones. I also ran the program without the line " if (all(rowSums(m.cand) > 0) & all(colSums(m.cand) > 0)) m.cand else NULL" this I get 12 such matrix, where as I should ideally get 16 (2^4).

Comment: I guess, I figured that out. I need to put repeats.allowed=TRUE  in the second permutations function as well.

Comment: I've changed my code to allow for different row and column dimensions. Please take a look.

Comment: I believe we still need repeats.allowed=TRUE in the lapply function as well. Try with matrixCombn(2,2); you will find one matrix missing which has all the elements as 1.

Comment: Yes I think you're right! I've changed the code accordingly. Mind you, the number of combinations very quickly blows up for larger values `ncol` and `nrow`. Enumerating all combinations brute-force like I do is definitely not very elegant nor fast...

Comment: You are right. This is not an elegant way. The number is 33millions for ncol,nrow =5 ...

Answer (score 0):

You can generate cartesian product like this

```
stores<-c("s1","s2","s3")
products <- c("p1","p2","p3")

expand.grid(stores,products)

   Var1 Var2
1   s1   p1
2   s2   p1
3   s3   p1
4   s1   p2
5   s2   p2
6   s3   p2
7   s1   p3
8   s2   p3
9   s3   p3
```

Once you have this data frame, you can then define which store sells which product by adding a column

```
dt <- cbind(expand.grid(stores,products), val = sample(0:1,9, replace = T))

> dt
  Var1 Var2 val
1   s1   p1   1
2   s2   p1   1
3   s3   p1   1
4   s1   p2   0
5   s2   p2   0
6   s3   p2   1
7   s1   p3   0
8   s2   p3   1
9   s3   p3   0
```

You can then use `reshape`

```
reshape(dt, idvar = "Var1", timevar = "Var2", direction = "wide")

  Var1 val.p1 val.p2 val.p3
1   s1      1      0      0
2   s2      1      0      1
3   s3      1      1      0
```

Comment: I don't think that's what OP is after. As far as I understand he wants to enumerate all possible matrix combinations subject to a specific constraint. Perhaps OP can clarify?

Comment: If I understand OP correctly (and I'm definitely not sure on that), the last matrix you give is *one possible combination*. It seems that OP wants to enumerate *all possible combinations*.

Comment: What I understand is, based on constraints which the user will define, the final matrix will be generated. If you see his example matrix contains the same. However this might be unclear, I am flagging this if the question is not updated

Comment: all possible combinations? this is too broad of a statement

Comment: I agree the question is not clear. OP needs to clarify. Also, please see my interpretation and solution.

Comment: @Hardikgupta, I have updated the question. Need to have all the possible matrices as Maurits has pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

You can add column names and replace values you like. This works on my end:

```
#No. of columns
n   <- 3  

#Values 
vec <- c(0, 1)  

#function returns a column vector that is a stack of the columns of x
lst <- lapply(numeric(n), function(x) vec) 

# 'expand.grid' creates a data frame that is the cartesian product of its 
#arguments 
preditction <- as.matrix(expand.grid(lst)) 

#Creating a prediction matrix that meets the condition- "**My main constraint 
#is : each store will sell at least one product and each product will be 
#sold by at least one store**."

preditction_matrix <- subset.matrix(x= preditction,
                                    subset = rowSums(preditction) > 0)
View(preditction_matrix)
```

Comment: I think this is not correct, the total number of rows in your case is 8, however it should be 9 - since this is cartesian product